# How to get image source path from another Binding image source path by clicking on binding image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I've Bind some image in a Listbox, when I will tap on a bind image that will be set in main image by source from bind image source.

This is the code where I want to show the image from Binding data.

```
<Grid x:Name="Icon" Margin="134,51,173,556">        
    <Image x:Name="MyIconImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Width="93" Source="" />
</Grid>
```

Here is the code where I've bind the data

```
<Grid Margin="0,366,0,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="List"
               ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemSource}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="IconListImage" Source="{Binding IconPath}" Width="48" Height="48" Tap="IconListImage_Tap"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="appName" Text="{Binding AppName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IconPath}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try SelectedValuePath?

```
<Image x:Name="MyIconImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Width="93" Source="{Binding ElementName=List, Path=SelectedValue}" />

<ListBox x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemSource}" SelectedValuePath="IconPath">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="IconListImage" Source="{Binding IconPath}" Width="48" Height="48" Tap="IconListImage_Tap"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="appName" Text="{Binding AppName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IconPath}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```